# How do I prevent jQuery from inserting the 'xmlns' attribute in an XML object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I've been using the new `$.parseXML()` method with jQuery 1.5.  Whenever I insert a new element into the XML object, that new element automatically gets the 'xmlns' attribute with the value "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml".  For example, see the code snippet below:

```
var myXml = "<one attr='a'><two attr='b'/><three attr='c'><four attr='d'/></three></one>";
myXml = $.parseXML(myXml);
$(myXml).find('three').append($('<five>some value</five>'));
```

The code creates the following element:

```
<five xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">some value</five>
```

How do I prevent jQuery from inserting the 'xmlns' attribute?  I've tried using the `.removeAttr()` method, but not even that seems to work.  Any ideas?

UPDATE:
The suggestion that user nrabinowitz offered was helpful in solving this problem.  Adding an xlmns attribute to the top level element does prevent the xlmns attribute from getting automatically assigned to each new element.  Still, I opted for another solution for my particular program.  I instead used the `.replace()` method to remove all the xlmns attributes after after I converted the XML object back into a string (to be displayed on a web page).

Comment: Have you tried adding your own XMLNS attribute to the root element? I suspect that in the absence of an explicit namespace, jQuery defaults to XHTML.

Comment: I don't think jQuery itself does any XML parsing at all. Instead, it lets the browser do it. (If jQuery had a complete XML parser built in, it'd be even more huge :-) *edit* yup checked the source - it just hands your XML over to a "DOMParser" instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to use

```
$(myXml).find('three').append('<five>some value</five>');
```

Comment: worked for me too, but the case was appending '<all-attributes></all-attributes> gave the element <all-attributes/> as desired

Comment: Worked perfect in Chrome, but in IE 11 there is nothing appended. Test it: http://jsfiddle.net/eygqwwgt/2/ Do you have a clue why?

Answer (score 4):

What happens is that the node you are inserting has another namespaceURI property.

Node derived from $.parseXML

```
$($.parseXML('<node/>'))[0].namespaceURI
// null
```

Your created node

```
$('<node>')[0].namespaceURI
// "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

You want your created node to also have a namespaceURI of the value `null`.

To make the created node inherit the namespace using jQuery, supply the original node as second argument to $() like `$('<five>some value</five>', myXml)`.

```
var myXml = "<one attr='a'><two attr='b'/><three attr='c'><four attr='d'/></three></one>";
myXml = $.parseXML(myXml);
$(myXml).find('three').append($('<five>some value</five>', myXml));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do like this:

```
var myXml = "<one attr='a'><two attr='b'/><three attr='c'><four attr='d'/></three></one>";

myXml = $.parseXML(myXml);

var el=xmlDoc.createElement("yourElement");

$(myXml).find('three').append($(el));
```

Comment: Your solution still gives the namespace within the "yourElement" tag. See at: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzfg7zpv/

Answer (score 0):

use this code that work in Chrome also in IE

```
var myXml = "<one attr='a'><two attr='b'/><three attr='c'><four attr='d'/></three></one>";
myXml = $.parseXML(myXml);
$(myXml).find('three').append($('',$.parseXML('<five>some value</five>')));
```

Comment: Please add some more context to your answer.